# printing uint8_t (char) with "%d" without casting takes the MSB and not the LSB?

Tags: c, gcc, casting, endianness, riscv

let's take the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

typedef enum
{
  BLAH = 9,
}fiz_e;

int main(void)
{
    fiz_e foo = BLAH;
    uint32_t bar = 9;

    printf("foo d %d x 0x%08x\n",(int)foo,(unsigned int)foo);

    if (bar == foo) printf("Hi\n");

    if (bar == (uint32_t)foo) printf("Ho\n");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Intuitively I would have said that this program displays:

```
foo d 9 x 0x00000009
Hi
Ho
```

BTW, this is also what I got when I compiled it on every online compiler I tried.

However, I'm (cross) compiling on a pulpino with riscv toolchain (riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc, gcc version 5.2.0), and I got the following result:

```
foo d 0 x 0x00000009
Ho
```

as if when not casting to uint32_t, it would take the msb and not truncate it...

Does endianness could explain this?

What does the standard say about this?

Comment: Where is the `uint8_t`?

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://ideone.com/L4twzd. I would not expect this to be any different on risc v.

Comment: @Eugene yes, I get the same result as you, but not when compiling with my toolchain, this is my I post this question. 
Is there something that could explain this?
(except maybe a memory corruption?)

Comment: What does it print if you replace `%d` with `%08x`? I don't believe in memory corruption here.

Comment: As far as I can tell this code should be fully portable (as long as there is `uint32_t` type defined. One thing to make everything clean - is to define `int main(void)`.

Comment: Seems to compile fine without warnings [using RISC-V on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/457xrYEnh). Unfortunately, godbolt doesn't execute RISC-V, and doesn't have the compiler version in question. But the generated code is there if a knowledgeable person wants to analyze it.

Comment: @Jabberwocky it would display 0x00000009

Comment: @FredLarson this is not a compilation issue, my first example was broken though

Comment: @GuillaumeD it _would_ or it _does_?

Comment: @GuillaumeD: I understand that, but I thought it was noteworthy that no compiler warnings were produced, and the generated code may be useful for someone who knows RISC-V (I don't).

Comment: Do the optimization levels change the behavior?

Comment: @Jabberwocky it does

Comment: @GuillaumeD very strange in deed. BTW you should change the question title, there is no `uint8_t` whatsoever in your code. And why do you think it's the MSB that is printed or not something else?

Comment: How are you "running" it? Emulator? Or a physical system? Is it bare-metal or hosted?

Comment: The output is as expected for me, i.e. has the two 9's; using -mabi=ilp32 -march=rv32imac with toolchain riscv64-unknown-elf-toolchain-10.2.0-2020.12.8-x86-64-linux-ubuntu14 from https://www.sifive.com/software.

Comment: Endianness is only a factor when pointers are used, and even then only when the pointers are used to refer to items smaller than the actual multi-byte data.  So, referring to individual bytes of an 4-byte int, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Intuitively I would have said that this program displays:
>
> ```
> foo d 9 x 0x00000009
> Hi
> Ho
> ```

*Analytically*, I would say that, too.

> I got the following result:
>
> ```
> foo d 0 x 0x00000009
> Ho
> ```
>
> as if when not casting to uint32_t, it would take the msb and not
> truncate it...

C doesn't work that way.

> Does endianness could explain this?

No.  The behaviors of arithmetic, comparison, and typecast operators are defined in terms of the value, not representation, of their operand(s), and it is the value of the result that is specified, not its representation.

> What does the standard say about this?

Summarizing some of the relevant implications of the standard that have not already been covered:

- enum types, such as your `fiz_e`, are integer types.
- All conversions, including those produced by typecast operators, are value-preserving when the value being converted is representable by the target data type.
- All of `int`, `unsigned int`, `uint32_t` (provided the implementation defines it), and your `fiz_e` can represent the value `9`.
- `int` and `unsigned int` are not affected by the integer promotions, so there are no additional conversions performed on the arguments to your `printf` call.
- overall, the behavior you describe for the cross-compiled binary does not conform to the language specification.

Insufficient information is given to say what's wrong with your toolchain or execution environment, or with details of your usage of those, that produces the non-conforming behavior you describe.